# dyn_cast vs. dynamic_cast in C++

Tags: c++, llvm, dynamic-cast

I come across a lot of dyn_cast in a codebase I am working on.

Is it the same thing as dynamic_cast ? or something different ? I searched a bit but couldn't find much info..

Comment: `dyn_cast<T>()` is an [operator from the LLVM](http://llvm.org/docs/ProgrammersManual.html#isa), and behaves like the standard C++ `dynamic_cast<T>` operator.

Comment: ah ok makes sense cause I am working on something related to llvm. thanks

Comment: @birryree: You should post this as an answer.

Comment: http://llvm.org/docs/ProgrammersManual.html

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`dyn_cast` is part of the LLVM API (and also is the first, second, third, etc.. hit on google) works just like dynamic_cast, however, one difference is that the class doesn't require a v-table like dynamic_cast. Please see the [manual](http://llvm.org/docs/ProgrammersManual.html#isa) for more info.

Answer (score 7):

Actually, it is `llvm::dyn_cast_or_null` which is equivalent to `dynamic_cast`.

These will produce a null pointer if passed a null pointer, whereas `llvm::dyn_cast` will bail.

Comment: Both `llvm::dyn_cast_or_null` and `llvm::dyn_cast` will return a null if the value is not of the required type. The difference between then is whether they accept nulls as arguments.

Comment: Good point about how `llvm::dyn_cast_or_null` can accept a null pointer as argument like `dynamic_cast`. However, the point about not requiring the class to have a v-table still holds. Thus, `llvm::dyn_cast_or_null` and `dynamic_cast` are not equivalent.